# Matlab's bsxfun() code

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

What does this do?

```
u = [5 6];
s = [1 1];
data1    =[randn(10,1) -1*ones(10,1)];
data2    =[randn(10,1) ones(10,1)];
data     = [data1; data2];
deviance = bsxfun(@minus,data,u);  
deviance = bsxfun(@rdivide,deviance,s); 
deviance = deviance .^ 2; 
deviance = bsxfun(@plus,deviance,2*log(abs(s)));
[dummy,mini] = min(deviance,[],2);
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing this without bsxfun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) will perform the requested element-wise operation (function handle argument) by replicating dimensions of the two input arguments so that they match each other in size. You can avoid the use of [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) in this case by replicating the variables `u` and `s` yourself using the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) to make them each the same size as `data`. Then you can use the standard [element-wise arithmetic operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html):

```
u = repmat(u,size(data,1),1);  %# Replicate u so it becomes a 20-by-2 array
s = repmat(s,size(data,1),1);  %# Replicate s so it becomes a 20-by-2 array
deviance = ((data-u)./s).^2 + 2.*log(abs(s));  %# Shortened to one line
```

Comment: The code result is sure equivalent, but `bsxfun` can save you both computing and memory resources (compared to `repmat` + operator combination). And sometimes it might be the difference between operating in memory or swapping. So I would personally use the `bsxfun` instead of `repmat` if possible.

Comment: @Binus: That may be true, but I imagine replacing *three* calls to BSXFUN with one simple vectorized solution gains you *something*, at the very least better readability.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Sometimes the readability is better than performance. But for everything else there is BSXFUN :D (I tend to overuse that function. Once I wrote complicated expression containing 3 BSXFUNs which was later replaced using one matrix multiplication...)

Answer (score 2):

`bsxfun` does binary operations element wise. It's useful when you need to subtract a vector (in this case `u`) from all the elements along a particular dimension in a matrix (in this case `data`). The dimension along which the operation is being performed must match in both cases. For your example, you can incorporate the code without `bsxfun` as

```
u1=repmat(u,size(data,2),1);
deviance=data-u1;
```

and so on for the other operations.