# Translating a line of Matlab (bsxfun, rdivide) to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, bsxfun

I am translating a Matlab function to Python. Unfortunately I am not a Matlab expert and it is hard for me to understand some lines, e. g. this one:

```
a = [[0, 1]; [2, 3]]
bsxfun(@rdivide, sqrt(a), a)
```

I did not really understand it yet, but I think this line does

```
r / a
```

for each row r of sqrt(a) (or is it each column?) and r / sqrt(a) can usually be translated to numpy as

```
numpy.linalg.solve(sqrt(a).T, r.T).T
```

The problem with this is: Matlab says the result is

```
       NaN   1.00000
   0.70711   0.57735
```

and numpy says it is

```
[ 1.  0.]
[ 0.55051026  1.41421356]
```

which was generated by

```
for i in range(2): print linalg.solve(sqrt(a).T, a[i, :].T).T
```

Where is the error? The matrices sqrt(a) and a are just examples. You can replace them by any other matrix. I am just trying to understand what bsxfun does with rdivide.

Comment: The matlab code is exactly equivalent to `sqrt(a) ./ a`, i.e. it divide each element of `sqrt(a)` by the corresponding element of `a` (it is also equivalent to `1./sqrt(a)`).

Comment: OK, so the author of the Matlab function wasn't a Matlab expert either. :D

Comment: What if the second matrix would be a vector, e. g. [1, 2]?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382654/matlabs-bsxfun-code
bsxfun resizes the matrices, plus it saves computational time and memory

Comment: I somehow don't get the same results for `bsxfun(@rdivide, a, [1, 2])` and `print a/[[1,2], [1,2]]`.

Comment: The `/` operator in Matlab is right *matrix* division, i.e. `A/B` is equivalent to `A * inv(B)`. If you want element-wise division you need `A./B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> b = np.sqrt(a)
>>> b/a
Warning: invalid value encountered in divide
array([[        nan,  1.        ],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.57735027]])
>>>
```

Since you need an [element-wise division](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), not matrix multiplication by the inverse, `numpy.linalg` is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first floor give you the transform of python code.

but if you want to know why code:

```
for i in range(2): print linalg.solve(sqrt(a).T, a[i, :].T).T
```

give the result

```
[ 1.  0.]
[ 0.55051026  1.41421356]
```

because `linalg.solve()` Solve a linear matrix equation, or system of linear scalar equations.

so the code `for i in range(2): print linalg.solve(sqrt(a).T, a[i, :].T).T`
will solve the linear matrix equations

```
0 * x0 + sqrt(2) * x1 = 0
1 * x0 + sqrt(3) * x1 = 1
0 * x0 + sqrt(2) * x1 = 2
1 * x0 + sqrt(3) * x1 = 3
```

so you will get the result

```
[ 1, 0].T
[ 3 - sqrt(6) , sqrt(2)].T
```

and in numpy shape `(2L,).T` is same as `(2L,)` so you will get the answer.